# Background Process without UI - android

Tags: java, android

I have an application Android and I need update the data without UI (Background Process)
I haven't idea about it

Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you have some ui interaction or on [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) if you do not want your app to be on top.